# Display custom widget, added as a shortcode in the correct place

Tags: widgets, shortcode

I've created a custom Widget and I would like to add it to the page content as a shortcode.

```
function show_custom_widget() {
    the_widget( 'WP_Custom_Plugin');
}
add_shortcode('custom-widget', 'show_custom_widget');
```

and I am using my shortcode in the post content as follows

```
[custom-widget]
```

As a result I get my Widget but it always displays at the top of the post content not in the place where I used the shortcode. How to make my widget display in the correct place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from a shortcode should be returned, not echoed. Echoing output in a shortcode will have unexpected output like you are seeing. `the_widget()` echos its output which is causing the issue. Unfortunately there is no similar function for returning the wdget output.

Luckily you can make use of a output buffer to overcome this issue. You can try something like this : (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
function show_custom_widget() {
    ob_start(); 
    the_widget( 'YOUR CUSTOM WIDGET' ); 
    $contents = ob_get_clean(); 
    return $contents;
}
add_shortcode( 'custom-widget', 'show_custom_widget' );
```

Comment: it works for me, but it execute the whole widget, in my case i just need the output of the widget, my widget contain some settings, so using above method it just reset everything.